# Manipulate Custom Values with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

```
<img src="" class="className" click="" id='button4' u="button6" r="button5" l="ele1" d="" />
```

I have an image wherein I need to change the value of the "U" data type. The "U" data was put in place by a developer I am working with, and I need to be able to use jQuery to change it's value in a loop on a specified timeline of every 15 seconds.

I can figure out the loop part, but I was just wanting to see if there is a way to manipulate the "u" value using jQuery.

Comment: Can you share the markup for the image tag and the logic for changing the value

Comment: It could be as simple as `$('img[u]').attr('u', '<new-value>')`

Comment: Sure, I have added the code above. As far as the logic, I am actually needing to change the "u" value on a loop of every 15 seconds.  So in this case, I may change "u" from button6 to button7 or **8 every 15 seconds.

Comment: Change it to `button7` (or whatever) based on what, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
setInterval(function(){
    var val = $('#button4').attr('u').substring(6);
    $('#button4').attr('u', 'button' + (1 + +val))
}, 1000)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rF7Rz/)

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `u` attribute (incidentally, if you switch from `u` to `data-u` then it'll be a *valid* attribute, under HTML5):

```
$('img').attr('u', function(i,u) {
    /* i is the index of the current image among all the images returned by the selector,
       u is the current value of that attribute */
    return u.slice(0, -1) + (parseInt(u.replace(/\D/g,''), 10) + 1);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xcU84/).

Though how the new value should be affected, by the loop or other variables, is unknown due to limited information in the question itself.

To demonstrate how to use the `data-*` attributes which allows custom attributes to be valid (under HTML5):

```
<img src="http://placekitten.com/400/500" class="className" click="" id='button4' data-u="button6" data-r="button5" data-l="ele1" data-d="" />
```

With the following jQuery:

```
$('img').attr('data-u', function (i, u) {
    return u.replace(/\d+$/,'') + (parseInt(u.replace(/\D/g, ''), 10) + 1);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xcU84/2/).

With reference to answers posted in another question ([Using a function to update a value within the data() method of jQuery sets the variable equivalent to the anonymous function, not the return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613473/using-a-function-to-update-a-value-within-the-data-method-of-jquery-sets-the-v)), the `data()` method doesn't accept a function as a callback, as `attr()` does, which is why I used the `.attr('data-u', function(){/*...*/})` rather than the `data()` method itself (though I *tried* that first, which didn't work).

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).
- [Regular Expressions (Mozilla Developer Network)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)
- [JavaScript Regular Expressions (Tech Pro tutorial)](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1214/javascript-regular-expression-enlightenment).
- [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
$("#button4").attr("u", "new value");
```