# Using a function to update a value within the data() method of jQuery sets the variable equivalent to the anonymous function, not the return value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I answered this question: [Manipulate Custom Values with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612828/manipulate-custom-values-with-jquery)

With this jQuery:

```
$('img').attr('u', function(i,u) {
    /* i is the index of the current image among all the images returned by the selector,
       u is the current value of that attribute */
    return u.slice(0, -1) + (parseInt(u.replace(/\D/g,''), 10) + 1);
});
```

[Link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16612943/82548), [JS Fiddle demo from that answer](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xcU84/).

But then I felt I should show how to do it 'properly,' using the custom `data-*` attributes allowed under HTML5 (rather than the invalid, albeit functional, custom attributes), so I adapted the HTML to:

```
<img src="http://placekitten.com/400/500" class="className" click="" id='button4' data-u="button6" data-r="button5" data-l="ele1" data-d="" />
```

(No, I've got no idea what the `click` attribute's meant to do, or why it's there, so I left it alone.)

And tested the following jQuery:

```
$('img').data('u', function(i,u) {
    /* i is the index of the current image among all the images returned by the selector,
       u is the current value of that attribute */
    return u.slice(0, -1) + (parseInt(u.replace(/\D/g,''), 10) + 1);
});

$('img').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).data('u'));
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xcU84/1/).

Now, with the `data()` method I realise that the attribute wouldn't be updated, which is why I used the `console.log()` to confirm the updated value, the output, however, is the anonymous function *itself*, not the value that I expected to be returned *from* that function. I realise this is unlikely to be a bug, and is probably the expected behaviour, but is there a way to use an anonymous function to update the attributes in the same way as, for example, that used within `attr()`, `text()`, etc..?

Comment: I was thinking about this yesterday, unfortunately `data` method doesn't accept a callback function. It sets the data value by storing that function not by using returned value of it. We have to use `each`.

Comment: That does seem like an oversight (though I accept that there were probably valid reasons for choosing to break continuity with the other methods).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `data` and many of the other jquery functions (such as `attr` and many others) is that `data` can store any type of object.  `attr` can only store string values.  Because of this, it is completely valid to want to store a function using `data`.

If the jquery team were to make a similar signature for `data`, they would need to somehow distinguish between wanting to store the function and wanting to evaluate the function.  It would likely get too confusing so they just did not include the ability to execute the function.

I think the best you can do is to use `each`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically your expectation is wrong.

jQuery's `.data` does not modify the data attributes of the elements at all; it simply *associates the data you provide with the element through a mechanism of its own choosing*.

The implementation is *intentionally* left unspecified, and `.data` does not process this data at all; you put something in, and when you later ask for it that is exactly what you get back. The data is totally opaque from jQuery's perspective.

It's true that `.data` provides pre-population of an element's associated data from its HTML `data-` attributes as a convenience feature, but that is not its main mission. And of course the opaqueness of the data is still upheld in this case: when you ask for data, you get back exactly what was specified in the HTML.

Comment: So presumably, to meet my expectations, I should use either `attr()` or `.each()` methods to modify the associated values?

Answer (score 1):

If you need this capability, you can easily add it:

```
$.fn.fdata = function( name, callback ) {
    return this.each( function( i, element ) {
        var $element = $(element);
        var data = callback( i, $element.data(name) );
        $element.data( name, data );
    });
};
```

Now you can use `$(sel).fdata( name, callback );` and do what you want in the callback.

It may be tempting to extend the existing `$().data()` method to add the callback capability, but as other pointed out, this would break any other code that depends on being able to store a function reference as data.

Of course, it's also possible that merely *adding* this `.fdata()` method could break other code - if some other code on your page also tries to use the same method name in its own plugin. So it may be wiser to make this a simple function instead. The code is almost identical either way:

```
function updateData( selector, name, callback ) {
    $(selector).each( function( i, element ) {
        var $element = $(element);
        var data = callback( i, $element.data(name) );
        $element.data( name, data );
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's not so much that I *need* it, I was just curious as to why it didn't work as I expected it to, given that it's so very different to expectations set up from use of (most of) the other jQuery methods.